# How to define a complex user usage rules in Mikrotik?

Tags: user-management, mikrotik

I want to define a 50 MB limit for each user in Mikrotik and after it is used, have a speed limit of 8 kbps speed for unlimited time. Furthermore, I would like this policy to be applied on a daily basis-meaning every day to have the 50 MB again...

Could anyone guide me on this?

Comment: Take a look at Mikrotik User Manager http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:User_Manager though I doubt it will do what you describe. As TomTom said you need to do this with other software that controls the router (Mikrotik has an API for thit kind of stuff)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Do NOT do this in mikrotik, use an external software for this. Mikrotik is a router, not something to manage your account limitations for you. This type of setp is normally done with - ah - software that controls the router.